# Cannot resolve symbol 'LocationClient' in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, google-play-services, location-client, location-services

I'm getting this error developing an application in Android Studio that I would like to use location services in.
I know this question has been asked before but I beleive the previous was with an app developed in Eclipse.

I beleive this may be an issue with the setup of Google Play Services
I have followed the instructions here http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html but I am now getting the error.
Could it be something to do with the fact that I previously installed Google Play Services through the SDK manager in eclipse before?
Any help would be appreciated, thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`LocationClient` was removed from the Play Services SDK a few months ago. You now use `GoogleApiClient`, `LocationServices.API`, and `FusedLocationProviderApi` to access the fused location provider in Play Services. [This sample project](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/Location/FusedNew) demonstrates how to get a location fix from this new API, and its use is also covered in [this blog post](http://javapapers.com/android/android-location-fused-provider/).

Answer (score 6):

**Small trick**

add `google play services` older version in your `build.gradle`

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:5.0.89'
```

I know this is not good solution. But it could solve your issue.

Answer (score 3):

Or if you just need the location service so use

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:x.x.x'
```

[Here](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup) you can find a list with some Google Play services API (scroll to Table 1)

P.S.: Can't add comments yet :(